# Android - Gallery of ImageViews with background images?

Tags: android, image, background, gallery, imageview

I am new to Android development, but familiar with the concept of views, controls, objects, XML layouts, C#, etc.

I'm trying to create a horizontally scrolling "list" of images using as much native functionality as possible.  (I'm not adverse to using custom components, but I'm trying to learn and optimize as much as possible before hacking something together.)

I currently have a Gallery with an adapter tied to it.  The adapter is creating ImageViews as seen in many basic tutorials.  On each pass of the adapter, I'm setting the background image for the ImageView.  My hope was that I'd be able to position the foreground image to lay on top of the background image at a specific X/Y position.  Unfortunately, I haven't made it past the point of getting the background image to behave the way I'd like it to.

Is this even possible with a simple Gallery and an ImageView?  Or, do I need to build a custom control of some sort (possibly using nested layouts?) and use that control on each iteration of the adapter?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

---

Here's what I'm seeing...

http://philaphan.com/public/stackoverflow/gallery1.png

...and what I'd like to see...

http://philaphan.com/public/stackoverflow/gallery2.png

Here's my code:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

    private Context mContext;

    public MyAdapter(Context c)
    {
        mContext = c;   
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return App.myList.size();   
    }

    public Object getItem(int position)
    {   
        return position;    
    }

    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;    
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        String imagePath = App.myList.get(position).thumbnail;

        ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

        i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 150));
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        i.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image_bk5);
        //i.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

        File f = new File(imagePath);

        if (!f.exists())
        {
            i.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_missing);
        }
        else
        {
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
            i.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }

        return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use salutations on Stack Overflow or try to circumvent their removal ([etiquette](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989)). Thanks.

Comment: @Kev - How are you able to add the short replies beneath each message? All I see are "link", "edit", and "flag", and the button at the bottom to add another answer. How do I reply to people that are trying to help me? As for my question, I'm still having difficulty getting it to work?

Comment: you can comment on your own posts but not anyone else's until you've gained 50 rep. The reason you can't comment at all is because you keep creating new unregistered accounts, each one different and I have to keep merging them. I suspect this is because you keep clearing your cookies or are posting from different machines each time. I'd recommend registering an account with SO to stop this happening.

Comment: Thanks for doing whatever you did to add the comments feature for me, Kev.

Answer (score 1):

I  think you can use:

```
i.setPadding(50, 50, 50, 50); //setpadding(left,top,right,bottom)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this..

replace  `i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE); with  i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);`

or check your background image . I think your background image width creating problem.

Comment: Sujit, I tried what you recommended, but now I'm seeing smaller overlapping images and no background images (or, the background images are sitting behind the foreground images with the exact same dimensions). http://philaphan.com/public/stackoverflow/gallery3.png

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this by using a HorizontalScrollView with a LinearLayout nested within it.  I then programmatically add two ImageViews -- one for the background and one for the foreground -- and I position the foreground at whatever X/Y that I choose.

I'd still be interested in knowing if this can be done within a Gallery control, if anyone sees this at a later date.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, if you want to add a background image to any kind of inflated gallery or ArrayAdapter or BaseAdapter, then - Make sure that the background image is defined in the parent layout, or parent view, for example the main layout, using the attribute "*android:background="@drawable/backupimage*". 
*Do not* set the background in the XML representing the custom-row/object-view of the repeating instances.

This way the background image will be displayed only once, appearing static behind all inflated objects, and not duplicated again and again on every single row/object.